# How to save a picture from a webcam to a file on the C drive

Tags: file-io, asynchronous, vb6, ip-camera

My application is extremely simple and to the point. When I click a button, it will go to an indicated IP address of a particular camera and  either stream video from the IP address in iexplore, or save whatever image is currently on the camera depending if user chooses stream or static mode.

What I am having trouble with is going to a camera in still mode and saving the file to a folder/file in my C:// drive.

*The only difference between still mode and stream mode is I attach '/image' to the end of the IP address when I just want a static image. If I open the IP address just by itself it will stream the video (which is working fine).

The following code shows what I have so far, which is opening the IP address in both stream and still mode, as indicated.

I am using the ShellEx module.

```
 Private Sub DS_Stream_Click()   // Cam 1 video stream
 ShellEx "http://999.999.999.100", vbNormalFocus
 End Sub

 Private Sub OS_Stream_Click() // Cam 2 video stream
 ShellEx "http://999.999.999.101", vbNormalFocus
 End Sub

 Private Sub Update_Btn_Click(idx As Integer) // Cam 1 still pic
 ShellEx "http://999.999.999.100/image", vbNormalFocus
 End Sub

 Private Sub ExecLink(Url As String, style As VbAppWinStyle)
 ShellEx "iexplore.exe "
 End Sub
```

So how can I go to 'Cam 1 still pic' IP address and save that image to my C drive somewhere( like a folder so I can go back and view all the still shots whenever I need to)?

I then plan on opening that image in a picture box on my form (so it scales down properly and retains clarity).  The image shown will be the latest picture saved to my folder on the C drive.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What ShellEx module? Is this an API, or a custom DLL?

Comment: ShellEx just allows me to open the URL in iexplore

Comment: No I mean, where did it come from? How is it implemented? Is it something you wrote? Since you are calling it to open everything modifying how things are opened would need to be done via ShellEx, or you'd need to use a different method. I just want to understand what you're using before I consider giving an alternate suggestion.

Comment: He's probably just causing the default browser to open that URL.  The silly thing is the AsyncRead method in VB6 can do what he wants, or he could use any of the many HTTP controls available to VB6 programmers.

Comment: Yea I'm just using it to open a URL as B.R. mentioned. Its lengthy open source code I found that just enables shell commands to be used, thats all. Ill look into the AsyncRead method. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

maybe u need use of api code to download from link such az a urldownload or inet control and another ways , maybe u need use of activex control for take picture from webcam by ip or without ip using and in win7 or higher you need access permission to create file (run as administrator)